# How to write specific HTML code with a specific custom field?

Tags: custom-field

In my Wordpress, each post can contains 2 buttons pointing to different links.

To make it easy for the end user, I want to create a couple of **Custom Fields** where the user only needs to enter the **URL of the link for Button A or Button B** (or both), but once inserted, it will actually write the following code inside the post:

```
<a href='Custom Field A Value' target='_blank' class='btn btn-primary fb-event'></a>

<a href='Custom Field B Value' target='_blank' class='btn btn-primary ra-event'></a>
```

That would be if both custom fields are filled and inserted, it can also include only one link.

So long story short, can I hardcode HTML code around specific Custom Fields and use the value inside the HTML?

Is that even possible?

Comment: Where do you have the problem, createing the custom field or the HTML output?

Comment: I can create the custom field, and output the value manually in the template or the post, but not automatize it so that the final user doesn't see the HTML, only introduces the URL and the rest is automatic..

Comment: Sounds like you're in need of custom post meta and the get_post_meta() function or one of the many plugins like ACF that help manage post meta data. Right now, your question is probably too broad for a good answer here. If you can update it with some code you've tried, you're more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// get_the_ID() will work if you're running within The Loop.
$fieldA = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name_of_fieldA', true );
$fieldB = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name_of_fieldB', true );

if( $fieldA ) {
    echo "<a href='".$fieldA."' target='_blank' class='btn btn-primary fb-event'></a>";
}
if( $fieldB ) {
    echo "<a href='".$fieldB."' target='_blank' class='btn btn-primary ra-event'></a>";
}
```

Comment: That was genius : )